# User activity reputation graph missing on Cross Validated

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, activity

Typically there was a user reputation cumulative graph on the activity page.
For example, mine for Meta Stack Exchange looks like this on Feb. 28, 2024 https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/341152/carl:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange]

However, on Cross Validated the graph seems to have recently disappeared and looks like this on Feb. 28, 2024 https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/99274/carl:

> [image: Cross validated]

Now, there is one subtle sign that different versions of software are being run on each site. Notice that the Activity button has a light blue oval background on the first post and a dark blue oval on the second.

Please comment as to which sites exhibit the new behavior, i.e., with no reputation graph, and would someone confirm that this is a bug, please?

Note, there was a different reason for similar questions in 2011, but this is a new occurrence.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Both links, when i go to activity, i see the rep graph.

Comment: prob a local thing, I would check extensions

Comment: The decision on whether or not to display the graph, (at least on math.se), depends on the width of your screen. Before trying anything else, open the page on your widest monitor, and maximize your window.

Comment: Check here for screen grabs: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36108/reputation-graph-could-you-add-an-option-to-see-it-in-the-old-cumulative-style/36109#36109

Comment: I am unable to replicate the reported problem when viewing at 100% Zoom.  
However, upon increasing the screen width to 130% Zoom, I am able to observe the "Top tag" section instead of the expected "Reputation graph". GIF for the reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cyLg.gif

Comment: @Arulkumar I had both at the same 110% magnification, at least I think so. In any case, the graph is back where it was. In any case, I increased the magnification and I reproduced what you claim at 130%. My default resolution is 2240 X 1260 pixels. If you include your comment as an answer, I will accept it for posterity.

Comment: @Carl - Hmmm, so the maximize the window trick didn't work? Interesting. Btw, I believe the official position of SE is that zooms other than 100% aren't supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to replicate the reported problem when viewing at 100% Zoom (which is recommended percentage in Stack Exchange).

However, upon increasing the screen width to 130% Zoom, I am able to observe the "Top tag" section instead of the expected "Reputation graph".

My screen display resolution is 1920x1080. **GIF for the reference**:

> [image: Wider screen]

Comment: FYI, the Top Tag bit is there in both cases. It just flows to a less prominent position when the graph is displayed.

Comment: @JonathanZ Yeah, I noticed that.